# Perl: can not get correct exit code from external program

Tags: perl, exit, novell-idm

I've searched everywhere, but I can't seem to find a solution for my issue. Probably, it is code related.

I'm trying to catch the exit code from a novell program called DXCMD, to check whether certain "drivers" are running. This is no problem in bash, but I need to write a more complex perl script (easier working with arrays for example).

This is the code:

```
#Fill the driverarray with the results from ldapsearch (in ldap syntax)
@driverarray =`ldapsearch -x -Z -D "$username" -w "$password" -b "$IDM" -s sub "ObjectClass=DirXML-Driver" dn | grep ^dn:* | sed 's/^....//' | sed 's/cn=//g;s/dc=//g;s/ou=//;s/,/./g'`;

#iterate through drivers and get the exit code:
foreach $driverdn (@driverarray)
{
    my $cmd = `/opt/novell/eDirectory/bin/dxcmd -user $username -password $password -getstate "$driverdn"`;
    my $driverstatus = $?>>8;
}
```

I've come this far; the rest of the code is written (getting the states).
But the `$?>>8` code always returns `60`. When I copy the command directly into the shell and echo the `$?`, the return code is always `2` (which means the driver is running fine). In bash, the code also works (but without the `>>8`, obviously).

I've looked into the error code `60`, but I cannot find anything, so I think it is due to my code.

How can I rectify this error? Or how can I track the error? Anyone? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong value passed to `-getstate`. You didn't remove the newline. You're missing

```
chomp(@driverarray);
```

Comment: Stupid that I didn't spot that! Thanks a lot, this was indeed the solution. Thanks a bunch for giving my perl courage back :)

Comment: Maybe the next question should be: any tips to spot this kind of errors? Surprisingly, I come from C# and Java programming, but we're spoiled with good IDE's and debuggers to spot these issues.

Comment: Generally speaking, `use strict; use warnings;`. Not in this case, though. How could Perl know whether you want a newline or now in the string you're building.

Comment: You should use String::ShellQuote's shell_quote to build the literals. Consider what happens if the password contains a semi-color, for example.

Comment: As I'm becoming more experienced: debugging does the trick for me. The newline is visible in the perl debugger. Thanks all for answering :)